# GWT to Javascript conversion

Tags: javascript, gwt

In javascript console if I do this,

```
   a = [1,2,3]
   Object.prototype.toString.call(a) // gives me "[object Array]"
   typeof a  // gives me "object"
```

If I create an arraylist in GWT and pass it to a native method and do this,

```
// JAVA code
   a = new ArrayList<Integer>();
   a.push(1);
   a.push(2);

   //JSNI code
    Object.prototype.toString.call(a) // gives me "[object GWTJavaObject]"
    typeof a // returns "function"
```

What exactly is the difference between the both? Is **GWTJavaObject** exactly similar to **Array**?

Why do `typeof` return "**object**" in pure javascript but "**function**" in  GWT?

Summary question is, what exactly are the GWT objects converted to in Javascript? **Full code** is here.

```
      public void onModuleLoad()
        {
                List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            list.add( new Integer( 100 ) );
            list.add( new Integer( 200 ) );
            list.add( new Integer( 300 ) );

            Window.alert(nativeMethodCode( list ));
                Window.alert(nativeMethodCode2( list ));
        }

        public static final native Object nativeMethodCode( Object item )
        /*-{
            return Object.prototype.toString.call(item);
        }-*/;

        public static final native Object nativeMethodCode2( Object item )
        /*-{
            return typeof item;
        }-*/;
```

Comment: You're essentially asking how GWT is implemented. Is that what you intend, or is there something more specific?

Comment: Thanks for quick response. Am trying to use JSNI inside GWT, thats where all these questions are popping up, because methods I write in JSNI works in browser console but not in GWT.

Comment: according to [this](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJSNI#passing-java), Java arrays cannot be accessed from JSNI code. Sorry… hope that page and helps you implement a workaround (surely it's possible).

Comment: Ah, looks like you need to mangle the type name `ArrayList<Integer>` and then you can call the `get` method from inside JSNI using some ugly syntax.

Comment: @Potatoswatter, not exactly. I was trying to implement a generic clone functionality using the suggestions given here. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459928/how-to-deep-clone-in-javascript and use it in GWT

Comment: You want to clone Java objects using JSNI code? Nesting objects across a language boundary (*any* inter-language interface) essentially locks you into reference semantics; generically cloning objects as values will be a world of pain.

Comment: Yes sir, I want to clone GWT Java objects using JSNI code. Or else every business pojo object should implement clone() method which I am desperately trying to avoid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An `ArrayList` in GWT is not translated to a pure JS array: it's a class extending `AbstractList` and implementing a bunch of interfaces, and this information should be kept when translated to JS so that `instanceof` checks (in your Java code; e.g. `instanceof List` or `instanceof RandomAccess`) still work as expected. An `ArrayList` is thus implemented as a *wrapper* around a JS array, see https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/tags/2.5.0/user/super/com/google/gwt/emul/java/util/ArrayList.java.

Note that a Java array is translated to a JS array, but be very careful about what you do to it in JSNI as you could break further Java assumptions (e.g. that an array has a fixed size).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Does that mean, GWT translation doesn't necessarily provide all the functionalities given by JS arrays? Am asking this because am trying to have a deep clone feature in my GWT application using the JSNI code as explained in this link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14273509/javascript-generic-clone-method-used-in-gwt-application. Should this attempt to find a generic "deep clone" method be debunked all together?

Comment: Like the example I have given, does the translated GWT object support the JS object features like obj.prototype or obj.constructor?

Comment: GWT-translated objects are JS objects, so they indeed have a prototype and a constructor.

Comment: But when am trying to get item.prototype or item.__proto__ in my above example its giving me 
com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptException: (null) @daridra.client.Attempt::nativeMethodCode(Ljava/lang/Object;)([Java object: java.util.ArrayList@17122202]): nul

Comment: Oh, these objects are not _standard JS objects_ when in Dev Mode, only in prod mode (or SuperDevMode)